# Can a property be declared with @synthesize only without @property?

Tags: objective-c

I found the following code in my project (using ARC). It looks like there is no property `adDisplay` declared. Only a synthesized statement and the compiler doesn't complain about it.

```
@interface MyClass() <MyProtocol> {
    AdDisplay * _adDisplay;
}
@end

@implementation

@synthesize adDisplay = _adDisplay;


...

@end
```

Do I need to add

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AdDisplay * adDisplay;
```

if I want to make sure `adDisplay` is strongly retained?

thanks

**Update**: it is declared in the protocol indeed. Does that count as instance variable?

Comment: Are you sure the property is not declared inside `MyProtocol` or inside the header? I think it does not make much sense otherwise.

Comment: good point. Yes, it's declared in the protocol. But how does that work in terms of memory management? Is it considered as instance variable?

Answer (score 1):

A property in Objective-C is a name for a pair of methods: a setter and a getter. Declaring a property means saying that these two methods exist (for readwrite properties).

There does not have to be any real storage or memory management. Historically, under manual memory management, `assign`, `retain`, or `copy` would affect how the methods are synthesized.

However, under ARC, this is no longer needed. When you declare a property as `strong` or `weak`, it does not affect the body of the method, but only the type of the ivar.

Since you have an ivar declared manually

```
AdDisplay * _adDisplay;
```

(as `strong`)

then `strong` or `weak` inside the `@property` declaration won't have any real effect, only as a documentation for the API consumers.

The following would also work:

```
@interface MyClass() <MyProtocol>
@end

@implementation

@synthesize adDisplay;

@end
```

Also note this used to be a common memory leak problem when migrating projects from MRC to ARC. A property declared as `weak`, with an ivar declared as `strong`.